# How does one pronounce the '@' symbol?

Tags: pronunciation, terminology, symbols

How can I pronounce *@*, *At* or *At the rate*?

Can I use it in a sentence? Please explain with an example.

Comment: you can use it to specify a time, e.g. "Let's meet @ 5pm", but don't use it in formal writing.

Comment: I'm sure I remember reading many years ago that "@" was called an arabesque; but I can't now find any conclusive reference to this on the web. So perhaps my recollection is faulty.

Comment: There is quite a list of pronunciations here... http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-pronounce.html

Comment: This symbol is mostly know as "arroba" at my country. It is used to mean 15 kgs or 33 pounds, and it's a pretty common unit in the farming scope, mostly with cattle. This (a unit of measurement) seems to be the original, intended usage of this little funny guy, but at some point it got some new uses.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How can I pronounce @ symbol: At / At the rate?

The "at mark", "at sign", or "at symbol" is its usual name. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign) its official name is "commercial at".

> Can I use it in a sentence? Please explain with an example.

It has no function in English sentences.

Comment: "My email address is john@generic.com."  You are saying that the `@` has no function here?  Or that this is not an English sentence?

Comment: @Kosmonaut: "My postal address is written 東京都渋谷区馬鹿街3－5－2 in Japanese." You are saying that  東京都渋谷区馬鹿街3－5－2 has no function here? Or that this is not an English sentence?

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock: Isn't it funny that you used `@Kosmonaut` when you replied to me?  You just used `@` in a meaningful way in English!

Comment: @Kosmonaut: you're reaching.

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock: Can you explain why you think so?

Comment: Aw please, @ has no function in English sentences.

Comment: Since "Aw please" is not much of an explanation, I'll just point out that @ has meaning within a string representing an email address, but no independent function in the sentence.  I have seen it as a sort of shorthand on invoices, like so:
  Your order #3475638, consisting of 560 bagels @ $3.59 per dozen, shipped on Tuesday. Please remit $167.53.

Comment: Another (fancier) name for it is "asperand" (from Wikipedia article). As cute as this is, it's not the most popular word, so people could confuse it with "ampersand", which is pretty common knowledge.

Comment: @Andy - Ampersand is this thing & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand not sure which wiki page you were referring to?

Comment: @Ex-user - @ has plenty of uses in an English sentence. Even more so since the emergence of the web. To say it has no use, do you mean it doesn't have a meaning, what is your argument? When giving an email address @ is used to indicate existence at a certain location replacing 'at' e.g. john 'at' hotmail.com. As indicated by @moioci it was previously used to indicate a price point for a multiple of an item.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperand

Comment: @Andy - My apologies. I misread your comment. I will leave my comment there as a testament to my stupidity along with the other people who get "asperand" mixed up with "ampersand".

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: That's perfectly okay; I had the exact same reaction when I first saw it. (The words are only 1 letter apart, though ever so slightly rearranged.) Besides, you pointed out that I didn't give a citation or link to anything in my comment, which would obviously help alleviate confusion. So, thank YOU for that!

Comment: NB I have never come across the sign referred to as "commercial at" in any contexts other than asking what the sign is called - in standard usage it is simply called "at sign" (or one of the others noted in the answer).

Comment: I would argue that it does have use in a sentence. Even when we say john dot doe at example dot com, we mean the very literary john.doe@example.com. If I wast to be discussing Perl @ could not be avoided.

Answer (score 43):

"At" as in "my email address is name at domain dot com."

Comment: I believe this should be the correct answer, since the question was actually how do I pronouce (as opposed to what is) this symbol.

Answer (score 3):

[**At sign**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign)

> The **at sign** (**@**), also called the **ampersat**, **apetail**, **arroba**, **atmark**, **acosta**, **at symbol**, **commercial at**, **curlat** or **monkey tail**, ...

If you would like to mention the symbol by name, **ampersat** seems to be the most easily recognized among its many names.

UrbanDictionary and GoogleAnswers mention that it is also called the 'amphora'.

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago, when email addresses were a rarity (probably 1988 or so), the British newspaper *The Guardian* asked readers of the technology supplement to answer this question. I think the most popular answer from readers was (not surprisingly) **at**: however my favourite suggestion, based on the visual appearance of the character, was **bellybutton**.

I think it's a shame that didn't catch on: doesn't "my email address is john dot smith bellybutton hotmail dot com" have a certain ring to it?