# How do you native speakers pronounce @ in an email address?

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one pronounce the '@' symbol?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2648/how-does-one-pronounce-the-symbol)

Do you just pronounce it as "at"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **at sign** (@), also called the at symbol or **asperand**,is formally an abbreviation of the accounting and commercial invoice term "at the rate of".

In recent years its meaning has changed to also mean "at" in the sense of "located at", especially in e-mail addresses. Now it's simply pronounced **at**.

Comment: I had no idea it existed before the email!

Comment: The term *asperand* is **extremely** dubious! Looking at the Wikipedia article [talk page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:At_sign), they’ve had a minor ongoing edit war for several years over whether this name should be included; and no-one there has ever given a reliable source — it almost looks like it’s could be a recent typo which only propagated into semi-official sources because it appeared on Wikipedia. *Ampersat*, though still dubious, is significantly more widely used. Other than this, good succinct answer — would +1 it if you removed *asperand*, or at least noted its dubiousness.

Comment: Oh — or of course also if you can give a more reliable source for it than Wikipedia, that would also allay my concerns.  :-)

Comment: I've always head it called either "the 'at' sign" or "commercial 'at'", since long before email was common. (I'm an old man.) I never heard the term "asperand" before reading the above post. That certainly doesn't prove it's not a real word -- I'm sure there are many words in English that I don't know, especially technical terms in fields outside my own -- but I don't think it's in common use. Maybe it's a term familiar to linguists.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The `@` symbol is just another way of writing *at*.

Comment: Yes - though (before the days of the internet) it was generally used for "at" in the sense of "at a price of ... (each)".

Comment: As in, "4 @ $2" means you are buying or selling 4 for $2 each, total price = $8.