# Does the "@" symbol have a name?

Tags: names, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pronounce @ symbol?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2648/how-to-pronounce-symbol)

In Spanish, *@* is called *arroba*.

I saw [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2648/how-to-pronounce-symbol), and it says it's called "commercial at" according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign). A lot of languages have a single word name for this.

Is there any single word name for *@*?

Comment: single word? is "at sign" a long phrase?

Comment: I mean just one word (not that "at sign" is complicated or long). I'm just looking for a formal name.

Comment: keep on trying then.

Comment: How was this marked as duplicate? Any logic coming forth?

Comment: In Polish it's called "małpa" (monkey). I mean officially. You usually dictate addresses in Poland using either that or saying it's "on <some server">.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's indeed called *commercial at*, but when reading it in an email address you would just say *at*.

So for instance:

*name@domain.com* would be read *name at domain dot com*

Interestingly, according to Wikipedia, the Spanish name *aroba* (from which comes the French *arrobase*) gets its name from a unit of weight equivalent to 25 pounds, for which @ was an abbreviation.

EDIT: so, to answer your question (because apparently I haven't) either you use just *at* (which is fine pretty much in any context), or you use two words.

Comment: Someone cares to explain the -1? I think I pretty much answered the question...

Comment: Just a trivia: in Portuguese we say _arroba_ too. We even say that when reading an email: _nome arroba domínio ponto com_.

Comment: @Bogdan: please reread my answer. I said that although the formal name is *commercial at*, when reading email addresses you would use just *at*, which is a single word.

Comment: @Bodgan: I updated my answer then. Anyway, on what basis would you say *at* is not formal? I am sure even the Queen would use it when telling someone Her email address.

Comment: @Bogdan: sorry but I cannot find any proof whatsoever that *ampersat* is more formal than *at* or *commercial at*. So much that the OED reports *commercial A* and *commercial at* but not *ampersat* or *asperand*. So those two words are definitely not formal.

Comment: @Bogdan: also see the discussion on the talk page on the wikipedia entry. Asperand/ampersat are neologisms with uncertain origin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:At_sign#.22Ampersat.22_.26_.22asperand.22_as_names_for_.40

Comment: I think, "There is no such word: you have to use a two-word phrase" is a fair answer to the question. If someone asks, "Who is Fred Smith's wife?" and you reply, "He isn't married", I don't think it's fair to accuse you of refusing to answer the question.

Comment: I have also heard this called *at-the-rate-of*, which is what it means, but it is common enough to be considered a tag of some sort. Ergo, you at-the-rate-of google dot com.