# What do you call this symbol @

Tags: technical, symbols

Do you call it the 'at' symbol or at the rate of or something else? I know the dictionary answer, more interested in the colloquial. Has a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign but it just lists many. Context: a requirements document where I'm listing allowed characters for a user name.

Comment: I've seen it used as a logograph for _at_ in email addresses and also in cost lists "64 blivits @ $3.66", and also for _each_ in a different list format "64 blivits, $3.66 @". The two meanings of _at_ are quite distinct semantically; one's locative and the other's existential. That, and the different syntax for _at_ and _each_, would lead me to call it a **logograph**, i.e, a one-symbol substitute for a word in the language, like &.

Comment: thank you. i thought I had deleted this question and added a comment to that effect before deleting it. But apparently that was undone! But that gave new information. You should add this comment or as an answer to the other question on the same subject  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2648/how-does-one-pronounce-the-symbol

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate, as the first question asks how to read the @ symbol, and this one asks the name of the symbol.  The answer is "at symbol, ampersat, apetail or commercial at," per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign